# WPF buttons with both image and text

Tags: wpf, button, styles

Here is my control template for the button style.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="EmailImage" Source="../Images/btn__icon_savedisk.png" Height="17" Width="17" Stretch="None" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="EmailImageTxt" Margin="20,0,20,0" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Static res:Localize.SAVE}" Background="{x:Null}" />
</StackPanel>
```

My problem is when I get mouse pointer over the area with the space between image and text button(image and text) is not selecting. I need to have mouse focus on all over the buttons.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Background="Transparent" to stackpanel and it works as expected.

---

An control with no background is usually called as non-hittable in XAML terms. So it is must to set a background to make the object respond to hits.

```
  <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="EmailImage" Source="Black.jpg" Height="17" Width="17" Stretch="None" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="EmailImageTxt" Margin="20,0,20,0" Foreground="Black" Text="gdfgdg}" Background="{x:Null}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="stackpanel"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```